# Inbox notifications should clear when I view/reply to a comment/answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I think it only makes sense that if you get a notification for say, a comment on your answer. When reading it (by clicking the "show all comments" link, or by replying to it), it should clear the notification automatically.

For notifications on answers for your questions, leaving a comment, editing, voting or accepting should all clear the notification.

Comment: Not exactly @KevinMontrose, the question you linked labels it a bug, I label it a feature request to be changed.

Comment: @Kevin I Agree with Madra, feature request can't possibly be duplicate of bug report. Voting to reopen this.

Comment: Clearing when you *act* on a notification (e.g. by replying to it or accepting an answer) makes sense, but merely clicking "show 17 more comments" (and one was addressed to you) shouldn't.  Sometimes you start to look and decide you need to save it for later -- in that case it should stay in the inbox.  Put another way, acting on *the thing that pinged you* is different from *acting on the bucket of things that includes the thing that pinged you*.  By analogy, just visiting a chat room doesn't (and shouldn't) clear pings therein; only clicking on the notification does that.